# Declare type synonym in 1 place & use it in multiple files

Tags: c#, typedef, using

Is there any way to do this in C#?

I want to do something like:

```
using TypeASynonym = TypeA;
```

in single place, and be able to use the `TypeASynonym` name in multiple .cs files.

Comment: Should be able to with partial class, but you'd only be able to use the synonym for that class.  You'd have to to it for each class you want to use it in.

Comment: no, not as far as I know. you have to write this in every cs file you want to use `TypeASynonym`

Comment: Just use find replace.

Comment: @Gilad, I wrote very simple example. Real cases could be more complex. Like `using MyType  = KeyValuePair<TypeA<TypeB>, List<TypeC>>;` and worse. Purposes of assigning a synonym are both: to minimize a possibility of mistake, when using such type & for better code readability.

Answer (score 0):

I've just advised to inherit new type from the type, I want to apply a synonym for. And name this new type by wanted synonym name.

Well, this inheritance-trick is much more than nothing, but! it doesn't work with `sealed` types, I want to assign synonym for.

So I leave question opened.